# Execute CMD command with Shell

Tags: shell, mingw

Trying to execute a .bat file from a shell script. This .bat file calls another .bat file.

The first bat file contains:

```
other_file.bat -c some_conf.xml
```

This means I cannot do:

```
start dir/my_file
```

But I need to do:

```
cd dir
cmd /k $(cat my_file)
```

But the command in my_file is not executed. I tried

```
cmd /k other_file.bat -c some_conf.xml

cmd /k "other_file.bat -c some_conf.xml"
```

None of these worked. But if i do **cmd /k** then enter manually **other_file.bat -c some_conf.xml**, it works...

Comment: Is this running in the Windows subsystem for Linux on Windows? I don't know what `cmd /k` does, it's not a Unix command...

Comment: It's running under MINGW64, on windows but it tries to replicate a linux shell if i understood correctly.

Comment: @Kusalananda `cmd /k string` *Carries out the command specified by string but remains*. Its inverse is `cmd /c` which is the analog of `bash -c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with Unix.

There is clearly a bug with MINGW64 stopping it from passing the cmd.exe command line correctly.  It is trying to be super tricky thinking that `/K` **must** be a path.

Either use a dash or double the forward slash:

```
cmd.exe //k other_file.bat -c some_conf.xml
cmd.exe -k other_file.bat -c some_conf.xml
```

How on earth did I know this (you might ask)?

If you look at the cmd.exe process that MINGW64 spawned, the command line looks like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe K:/ other_file.bat -c some_conf.xml
```

See the `K:/`?